# KVM-Qemu Windows 10 guest VM can't connect to Samba Share

Tags: ubuntu, windows, virtual-machine, samba, kvm

When paste my linux host IP where i have Samba server, into the windows URL bar and hit enter, the connections that i created in Samba appear but then i am not able to connect, it appears [this message](https://i.ibb.co/gjkXZXX/image.png)

[image: Img]

This tutorial *[Windows 10 can't connect to Samba share (Guest access)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e53tueIdvrE)* aims exactly to my problem, but i followed the steps but with no luck, the error persists.

Here is my Samba configs:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes



# Custom connection 1
[Anonymous]
    comment = Anonymous File Server Share
    path = /media/bz/Data/.VM-shared
    browseable = yes
    writable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    force user = nobody

# Custom connection 2
[Public Directory]
# path = /Public/Files
   path = /media/bz/Data/.VM-shared
   guest ok = yes
   read only = no
   browseable = yes

# Custom connection 3
[Private Directory]
# path = /private/files/
   path = /media/bz/Data/.VM-shared
   valid users = me
   read only = yes
   browseable = no
```

Every time i edit the `smb.conf` i run

```
testparm
sudo systemctl restart smbd
sudo service smbd restart
```

## Other steps i did:

### Change permissions in host shared folder

```
sudo chmod -R 0775 /path/to/shared/folder
sudo chown -R nobody:nogroup /path/to/shared/folder
```

Note: if i run `/etc/init.d/samba`: gives me this error `No such file or directory`

### Add rule in UFW

`sudo ufw allow samba`

**Note:** I tested disabling completely UFW but the problem persisted

### Add my user to Samba

`sudo smbpasswd -a My_username`

### Installation

`sudo apt install samba smbclient`